# Run time error 109 - Using Set for a string to set a file path for an object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, set, runtime-error

I am trying to set two different workbooks outside of my current workbook as MainDatabase and ChangesDatabase, so I can easily activate them and select which sheet I want to use seamlessly between then two workbooks outside of the workbook VBA is running on (sorry for my linguistics I am very very new to VBA).

I am trying to declare ChangesDatabase in this case, as a Workbook and then assigning a string "Cd" as a file path and finally setting the string as ChangesDatabase file path. I am trying to activate both workbooks like so:

```
ChangesDatabase.Activate
Changes.Select
```

AND ALTERNATE BETWEEN THE FOLLOWING:

```
MainDatabase.Activate
HE171.Select
```

[image]

Here is the code:

```
'Actions for when the "Confirm Changes" button is clicked
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'Declaring the message box variable
    Dim nConfirmation As Integer

'Declaring the Changes_Database Workbook and worksheet(s) we want to work with, in this case 1 Workbook and 1 Worksheet
Dim ChangesDatabase As Workbook
Dim Changes As Worksheet

'Declaring the variable Cd (Changes_Database acronym) as the "Changes" sheet filepath
Dim Cd As String
Cd = "\\Databases\Technology_Changes\Changes_Database_IRR_20-2S_New.xlsm"


'Workbooks("Changes_Database_IRR 20-2S New.xlsm").Sheets ("Changes")

'Setting the file path for the Workbook with the "Cd" string that was previously declared
Set ChangesDatabase = Workbooks.Open(Cd)

'Setting the sheet, can have multiple, in this case we only require one sheet
Set Changes = Sheets("Changes")

'Declaring the Main Database Workbook and worksheet(s) we want to work with, in this case 1 Workbook and 1 Worksheet
Dim MainDatabase As Workbook
Dim HE171 As Worksheet

'Declaring the variable Md (Main Database acronym) as the "HE 171" sheet filepath
Dim Md As String
Md = "\\Databases\Database_IRR 20-2S New.xlsm"

'Workbooks("Database_IRR 20-2S New.xlsm").Sheets ("He 171")

'Setting the file path for the Workbook with the "Md" string that was previously declared
Set MainDatabase = Workbooks.Open(Md)


'Setting the sheet, can have multiple, in this case we only require one sheet
Set HE171 = Sheets("HE 171")

'Sets the Main Database as the active contents
MainDatabase.Activate
HE171.Select
```

I put comments on every line and just hid the actual file path name on my screenshots and any unrelated comments I made for the code. Please let me know thanks

Comment: Please paste your actual code and note a screen shot.

Comment: You don't use a path as the index into the `Workbooks` collection, just the file **name** (since you can't have two files of the same name open).

Comment: If your file is open, refer to it by name. If your file is not open you need to open it with file path using `Workbooks.Open(fp)`

Comment: How do I edit my post to add the code in rather than just the sreenshot. thanks

Comment: You'll find an [edit] link below the question which you can use to change the content :-)

Comment: Thank you! still struggling with this code and understanding it if anyone else has some insight

Answer (score 1):

I believe to assign to the Workbook object you need to have the Workbook open. This could be the cause of your error.

You could try this:

```
Set ChangesDatabase = Workbooks.Open(cd)
```

Comment: I added the Open(Cd) but for some reason it's opening the other workbooks and no closing them and asking me to update link

Comment: This will open whatever Workbook you reference. To disable the Update Links popup try using `Application.EnableEvents = false` Just remember to enable them again after it's open.

Comment: Do I need to write a macro that enables them in the workbook that I am disabling the events in?